# Storing a String with ASCII values into an Array and use RSA key

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, rsa

I am fairly new to coding. I am trying to take a user input, change their text into ASCII values, and then encrypt this with an RSA key i made. 
Currently i have this code:

```
public class RSA {

  public static void main(String args[]){
    int p = 11; 
    int q = 17;
    int n = p*q; //187
    int phi = (p-1)*(q-1); //160
    int e = 7;
    int d = 23; 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your message: ");
    String clearMsg = input.nextLine();
    String trimmedClearMsg = new String(clearMsg.trim());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (char c : trimmedClearMsg.toCharArray())
      sb.append(String.format("%03d",(int)c));
    BigInteger asciiMsg = new BigInteger(sb.toString());

    System.out.println(asciiMsg); /*i print this out to check i have transferred to ASCII */

    byte[] asciiArray = asciiMsg.toByteArray(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
      double keyCipher = Math.pow(i, e)%n;
      System.out.println(keyCipher);
    }
  }
```

Current output is:
Please enter your message:
hello
104101108108111    (this is the ASCII value of hello)
0.0
1.0
128.0
130.0
115.0
146.0

I am not sure why this is printing these numbers, i am expecting the encrypted version of 104101108108111.

Any guidance will be appreciated!! :)

Comment: Don't use BigInteger to store your message; use byte array instead

Comment: "i am expecting the encrypted version of 104101108108111." Well, the encrypted version will contain arbitrary bytes, so you have to decide how to want to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (assuming that you got RSA details right):

```
public class RSA {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int p = 11, q = 17;
    int n = p * q; //187
    int phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1); //160
    int e = 7, d = 23;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your message: ");
    String msg = input.nextLine().trim();

    byte[] msgBytes = msg.getBytes();
    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[msgBytes.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < msgBytes.length; i++) {
        //below works only because n==187
        encryptedBytes[i] = (byte) (Math.pow(msgBytes[i], e) % n);
    }

    System.out.println("Encrypted string        : " + new String(encryptedBytes));
    System.out.println("Encrypted string base64 : " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedBytes)));
  }
}
```

please note it uses `Base64` which is avaliable from Java 8 onwards.

Comment: Nah, that won't work for a few reasons. First, not your fault, you copied his bug of encrypting the array index `i` instead `msgBytes[i]`. Secondly, `(byte) (Math.pow(i, e) % n)` won't work for large value of i because a double is not big enough to hold the result. Thirdly, `new String(encryptedBytes)` is not really sensible because the cipher bytes are not likely the encoding of any valid Unicode string.

Comment: Good catch about encrypting `i` vs. `msgBytes[i]` @JamesKPolk !!!
I did comment inline about the cast to byte. Lastly `new String(encryptedBytes)` was only to illustrate that one needs to encode it to have any chance at storing the encrypted text (and then decoding and decrypting).

Comment: The main issue is that `Math.pow(msgBytes[i], e)` is a double which only has 53 bits of precision, so if `msgBytes[i]` is 191 or larger it will lose information. Of course if it is 187 or larger the encryption operation itself will lose information because it is occurring mod 187.